# How to run batch file(.bat) from Jmeter

Tags: batch-file, jmeter

I'm new to Work with jmeter and I want to run batch file ,I have tried to run batch file from BSF sampler using this command

*exec("C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe../stopwas.bat")*

and it displayed an error message

"there is no script engine for file extension .bat"

- also I have tried to run batch file from OS process sampler and I wrote the command as :

  ```
  command :cmd
  stopwas.bat
  ```

also it failed can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 4):

For OS Process Sampler I guess you need to provide a command parameter like `/c` or `/k`.

So:

- Command: `cmd`
- Command parameters:

  - `/c`
  - `c:\somefolder\someotherfolder\stopwas.bat`

Mention that you have to use **full path** to your .bat file.

Another option is executing it via [Beanshell Sampler](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c c:/somefolder/someotherfolder/stopwas.bat");
```

Comment: Is It possible to run a jar file from OS process Sampler and what should be the value in Command and Command Parameters

Comment: It is. In "Command" input specify the full path to `java` executable and for each space-separated parameter create a new "Command Parameter", like: first parameter - `-jar`, second parameter - full path to .jar file, third parameter - jar file parameter, etc.

Comment: Is It possible to recoed the activities that is carried out on the jar file using the recording controller