# Why the BAT file launched from JMeter OS Sampler is not triggering the Maven execution?

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, jmeter

**Summary:-** I need lots of dynamic data for my performance testing and it's not possible to generate those test data from Jmeter itself. Hence, I wrote a Java code which will generate these dynamic test data and will put those data into the excel file. This excel file can be consumed by JMeter script for the performance testing. Every iteration in JMeter needs a new set of test data and that's why I have created a bat file which will trigger the Maven execution(it's just mvn clean test) and will generate the fresh set of test data before each of iteration. Everything is working fine till this point. I just need to run the bat file from JMeter to trigger the test data creation before each iteration and that's the problem which I am facing

**Problem:-** As mentioned in the link [How to run batch file(.bat) from Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302665/how-to-run-batch-file-bat-from-jmeter) and as suggested by user @Dmitry T, I have added the OS sampler with the given parameters(See the screenshot below) but it is not starting the Maven execution. It is hitting the bat file(I put some msg command to check) but somehow it is not starting the execution. I tried the other solution given by the same user about using the Beanshell Sampler and running the command

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c D:/XXXX/XXX/XXXX/GenerateTestData.bat");
```

This is also not working. Am I missing something here? Please let me know if there is any solution for this? Appreciate any help on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file is most likely not designed to work properly with current directory on execution being different to the directory containing the batch file. The current directory can be any directory. Very common are the directories `%SystemRoot%` (Windows directory) and `%SystemRoot%\System32` or `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` (Windows system directory) as current directory, whereby any directory can be the current directory on running a batch file.

A batch file referencing other files or directories relative to the batch file directory should set the current directory to the batch file directory or reference all directories and files with full batch file path.

The argument 0 of a batch file is always the batch file itself. The help output on running in command prompt window `call /?` explains how to reference an argument with a modifier. In this case `%~dp0` should be used to get full path of the batch file.

So in the batch file can be used at top:

```
@echo off
cd /D "%~dp0"
```

The current directory is set with second command line to the directory containing the batch file as long as the batch file is stored on a drive with a drive letter.

There is another method to make the directory of the batch file the current directory which works even with batch file being stored on a network resource and the batch file is executed using its UNC path.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0" || exit /B

rem Other commands accessing files and directories in batch file directory
rem using no path or a path relative to current working directory.

popd
endlocal
```

The help output on running in a command prompt window `pushd /?` describes why this code works even with a UNC path on command extensions enabled which is made sure by the second command line which defines together with first command line completely the execution environment for the batch file without depending on configurations outside of the batch file.

Another solution is referencing all files and directories in batch file directory with full path which means with using `%~dp0`, for example `"%~dp0ExcelFile.xlsx"`.

**Note:** The path string referenced with `%~dp0` always ends with a backslash which is the directory separator on Windows as explained by Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). Therefore concatenation of `%~dp0` with another string like file/folder name or wildcard pattern should be done always without using an additional backslash for a 100% correct full file/folder/pattern argument string.

Answer (score 1):

1. In the `Command` input provide full path to the `cmd.exe`
2. Change the `Working directory` to where your batch file lives
3. Use just batch file name in the `Command Parameters`

Something like:

[image]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter#comment-5116786908) article for more details.

Alternatively you can use [Maven Exec Plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to run your custom command before running the JMeter test

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri for your help. As usual, your solutions always work :).